# How to avoid type-checking parameters in this scenario

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism, typing

I wanted to implement a basic Graph structure that could later be extended to more specific types of Graph (Dialogue, Behavior...) which would each also need specific types of nodes which would derive from a Node base class.
My Graph base class looks like this right now

```
public abstract class Graph {

  private Dictionary<Node, List<Node>> adjList;
  
  public abstract void AddNode(Node node);
  public abstract void RemoveNode(Node node);
  public abstract void AddEdge(Node node, Node destNode);
  public abstract void RemoveEdge(Node node, Node destNode);

}
```

My problem is that I would have to typecheck in the implementation of those methods to prevent users from adding, for example, a DialogueNode to a QuestGraph. Are there any design patterns to fix this? Or should I just do without a base class and write some code multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I would have to typecheck in the implementation of
> those methods to prevent users from adding, for example, a
> DialogueNode to a QuestGraph.

You could define an abstract generic class and specify a specific Node subtype for each implementation.

For example in Java :

```
public abstract class Graph<T extends Node> {

  private Dictionary<T, List<T>> adjList;
  
  public abstract void AddNode(T node);
  public abstract void RemoveNode(T node);
  public abstract void AddEdge(T node, T destNode);
  public abstract void RemoveEdge(T node, T destNode);
}
```

And the `QuestGraph` subclass could be like :

```
public class QuestGraph extends Graph<QuestNode> {
  public void AddNode(QuestNode node){...}
  public void RemoveNode(QuestNode node){...}
  // And so for ...
}
```

> Are there any design patterns to fix this?

Design patterns don't enforce that kind of rules and in a general way is not designed to limit polymorphism abilities.